# get distinct values from array ( as String not List or ArrayList) in visual basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, duplicates, distinct-values

All of the values of labels are stored into an array when the button is clicked

```
Dim myArr(3) As String           
myArr(0) = 1.Text  
myArr(1) = 2.Text
myArr(2) = 3.Text  
myArr(3) = 4.Text
```

I am trying to remove duplicates from my array of labels, I've watched tutorials about distinct but it shows List and ArrayList. I've also coded for removing duplicates from my array

```
Dim testDist As String = myArr.Distinct().ToString  
           For Each NOW As String In testDist  
                Dim labelShow As String = String.Join(",", NOW)  
                Label7.Text = labelShow  
            Next
```

But it only shows `]` as output. Can you please help me.

Comment: *"I am trying to remove duplicates from my array of labels"*. That would be difficult, given that you don't have an array of `Labels`. You have an array of `Strings`.

Comment: right, thanks for pointing that @jmcilhinney.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track with `String.Join` but you should have just passed the result of `Distinct` directly:

```
Label7.Text = String.Join(",", myArr.Distinct())
```

For the record, `Disinct` returns an `IEnumerable(Of String)`, i.e. a list that can be enumerated.  `String.Join` will accept basically any enumerable list of `Strings` or `Objects`, including arrays or generic `Lists`.  It the items are not `Strings`, their `ToString` methods will be called.

Comment: "Distinct is not a member of system.array"